# How to the user inputted values from datagridview in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

i have been loaded an empty datagridview with winforms which has fields like id,name,contact no etc . the user has to input values to the datagridview at the runtime. How can i get those values that have been entered by the end user?

I'm already tried the following codes but it is throwing null value exception

```
id = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
id = dataGridView1[row,column index].Value.ToString();
```

I tried these codes,can any one suggest how can i get those values from DGV or any other alternative to get the values from the user

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the proper event handler, like rowenter and do the following:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value;
```